# SQL Server Embedded Edition vs SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, embedded

Can anybody shed some light on how these SQL products compare? No need for essays, only highlights such as "X supports this, while Y doesn't".

- How is efficiency affected as the database grows larger

  - Inserts
  - Updates
  - Selects
- What kind of transactions are supported
- What support is there for multiprocessing

  - Access from concurrent *processes*
  - Access from concurrent *threads*
- Data access is in-process or via server process
- Key feature of either product that is worth mentioning

Also, any (positive or negative) experiences from people who have used *both* products (don't want opinions - just observations).

The reason I'm asking is that it's hard to penetrate the marketing fluff surrounding Microsoft's embedded SQL product.

Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific about your particular requirements - this is a [very broad question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) as it stands

Comment: The last bullet is somewhat broad, but I want to capture people's experiences with the products. What is marketed is not always reality...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question "What support is there for multiprocessing":

- SQL Server CE and SQLLite are single-user DBs that work in your app and deployed as DLLs
- SQL Server (Express and above) (and MySQL, Oracle, Postgres et) are server engines where you submit a request

Either you have *proper* multiprocessing or you don't: not much grey area in between. The rest of your questions don't matter because of this.

An as example, SQLLite locks tables locking so you don't have much concurrency even if it nominally supports multiple processes

Edit, about SQL Server CE from SO

- ["SQL Server CE in a multi user scenario - is this really, really stupid?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992713/sql-server-ce-in-a-multi-user-scenario-is-this-really-really-stupid)
- ["What is the number of maximum concurrent connections for Sql CE 3.5?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240463/what-is-the-number-of-maximum-concurrent-connections-for-sql-ce-3-5)

It looks like SQL Server Express is recommended for multi process access

Comment: I know SQLite responds with a generic "it's locked" response, if a second process wants to access the data concurrently. Would SQLCE do the same, or is it possible to have the calling process be put in a wait state?

Comment: @Jörgen Sigvardsson: added more